# How to tell which API in .NET is cross platform?

Tags: c#, .net

The intro is a bit lengthy, key question is bolted at the bottom.

So, I've been programming in C# almost exclusively for few years now. I feel quite comfortable and happy with it. However on thing that I'm struggling with since the beginning is deep understanding of .NET platform(s). Especially I don't know which libraries I can use so that my application is not constrained to windows only. When I started around 4 ya I was only told that my application suppose to be targeting .NET Framework 4.5 because there are "some problems" with other frameworks. Apparently the person who told me to use .NET Framework 4.5 was even more confused then me because he though he can't use new versions of C# with old version of framework. Since then, there came few new versions of the frameworks, .NET Core and now just .NET. And now it turns out that I really can't use new C# version when targeting old frameworks. This however is not the most important issue... My main issue is to tell which API is really available on all platforms. I remember reading the news that WPF is now available on .NET core, so I started to mess around with it just to find out after a while that it's still Windows-only. To add more to confusing you also have .NET Standard, platform extensions, mono and few other misleading  goodies. Now I'm sitting here after countless hours of C# programming and I'm unable to answer for sure a simple question like.

**Is this class available on all platforms?**

For example I'm interested in using a [Dispatcher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.threading.dispatcher?view=net-5.0) class.

At the bottom, under "Applies to" I see:

.NET 5.0, .NET Core 3.0, 3.1 ...

So this must mean when I compile my app for Core 3.0  using it, it will be available everywhere?

But at the top I see:

Namemespace: System.Windows.Threading

Assembly: WindowsBase.dll

Does "Windows" means this is only available on window?

Also I see the same "Applies to" section under [Window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.window?view=net-5.0) class. But this class is part of `PresentationFramework.dll` which is WPF, which means I can use it only in Windows OS, right?

Another thing which confuses me even more - the [Image](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image?view=net-5.0#applies-to) class "Applies to" specifies .Net Platform Extensions. I though WPF on .NET Core is available only with Platform Extensions. So, why the Image documentation specifies Platform Extensions, but Window documentation don't?

Also in "remarks" of [System.Drawing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing?view=net-5.0#remarks) there is a note, basically saying you should not use classes form that namespace (great, now I probably need to check remarks of all namespace I use...)

So (this is not another question, but rephrased on) **given a class X of .NET how can I tell where it will be available?**

From now on I'm starting to be afraid of even using `System` namespace...

#### Update

1. As I see some confusion in comments I would like to clarify.
   By "cross platform" I mean all major operating systems where .NET runtime is available. I do not consider Xamarin cross platform.
2. Although class like `Dispatcher`is probably mostly associated with WPF, it's not a presentation-specific thing and I found it useful in scenarios different than GUI operations.

Comment: If your application or class library targets .NET Old, it's not cross-platform. If you target .NET Standard or .NET Core (.NET 5 is .NET *Core* 5), it is. As for WPF/WinForms, these are only for Windows, so you don't even need to check if those namespaces are cross-platform. The only cross-platform desktop technology is Xamarin Forms

Comment: Given how easy it is to find out what's available, what's the actual question?

Comment: When .net MAUI comes out, everything will be cross-platform, or so I understand.

Comment: @insane_developer close. MAUI is just a UI framework similar to Xamarin. You write the same code and it can deploy to multiple different devices/OS. .Net Framework, .Net Core, .Net Standard, and .Net 5 are still their own thing.

Comment: I share the same opinion as you. Microsoft has make it so complex by having so many frameworks and now having lot of platform specific libraries in .NET core. The way I solved this is to add docker support and run the app on docker. If something is not supported, it throws an exception. There were many exceptions with System.Drawing which were hard to fix

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Maybe I suck at this but I don't know. Is Dispatcher class available, and how you know it?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Xamarin is not cross platform. It's not available on Linux. The only GUI library I found that is apparently available in all operating system is Uno Platform.

Comment: @insane_developer I don't actually know much about this but MAUI is essentially next version of Xamarin.Forms an will be available on the same platforms which is just Windows and mobiles.

Comment: @Pawcio cross-platform doesn't mean it's available in *all* platforms. But Xamarin Forms *is* the only cross-platform UI stack available from Microsoft. Uno isn't Microsoft's. Is your *real* question whether there's a Desktop UI stack that works on all the (unspecified) platforms you want? That's very different from what yu asked.

Comment: @Pawcio asking whether a stack-specific class like `Dispatcher` exists on platforms that the stack itself doesn't run on is the wrong question to ask. `Dispatcher` is only used in WPF, which is only available on Windows. It's not used all that much since `async/await` came about and the need to use `BeginInvoke` went away

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I've added some clarification in question. I'm not interested in UI here. And I also don't know why you bring `asyn/await` here as those two are for two different things. `async/await` don't allow you to specify priorities and don't give other goodies. You can actually await a `DispatcherOperation`. How this answers my question if it's available?

Comment: @Pawcio the idea is that you can create a desktop application based on MAUI, and it will run on all supported platforms (Windows, Linux, Mac).

Comment: @insane_developer well, it's a bit off topic, but were did you read that Linux will be supported?